# cURL in Laravel and goDaddy API

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, godaddy-api

I am making a domain purchase call via the godaddy API. I have been successful purchasing a domain on their test environment: https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains

```
                $bodyContent=json_encode($bodyContent);

                $ch = curl_init();
                $timeout=60;

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bodyContent);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

                $result = curl_exec($ch);

                $dn = json_decode($result,true);
                $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                dd($http_status);
```

The URL endpoint:

```
$url = "https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/purchase";
```

When i now try and do this on laravel and `dd(http_status)` i get a `404` error. I can provide more details on the `$bodyContent` but for now just know the same variable works fine in the godaddy environment. I am new to curl so something must be wrong in the above code snippet

Comment: can U show us $url, plz?

Comment: $url = "https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/purchase";

Comment: use http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/ for curl request, Laravel have "guzzle" out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable), Laravel provides it out of the box. Your request will be like this (don't forget to paste your Api Keys):

```
// Initialise new Client
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

// Make headers
$headers = ['Authorization' => 'sso-key [API_KEY]:[API_SECRET]']

// Make body (without json_encode)
$body = ['name' => John, 'age' => '21'];

// Make request with your headers and body
$responce = $client->post('https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/purchase', [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'form_params' => $body
]);

// Get Api responce content
$result = $responce->getBody()->getContents();
```

> Notice! I`m use 'POST' reques, becouse for ['v1/domains/purchase'](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/purchase)
>   available only POST method

Comment: I will try that. Could you please add how to pass the $bodyContent json object in your code snippet. This is the same object that contains all the registrant data that must be passed to the endpoint to register the domain

Comment: Thanks for that. I made the changes and i get the errors: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given

I am very confident that nothing wrong with my $body json object as its the one i used in testing and it worked

Comment: ok forms_params required an array and not a json_object. I am however still having errors: 401 Authentication error - i assume the headers are meant to only have 1 'sso-key' and not 2 as shown up there

Comment: I had already changed that and it still doesn't solve my authentication error